# I am getting cropped warning output with Visual & Installer when compiling my script

Tags: inno-setup, visual-and-installer

I am using the latest version of Visual & Installer:

```
        ================================================
6>       Visual & Installer - Inno Setup Compiler (1.0.4.9)
6>       Copyright (c) 2012 - 2020 unSigned, s. r. o.  
6>       Visit http://www.visual-installer.com/ for more information. 
6>      ================================================
```

I have just noticed at the bottom of the error log what looks like incomplete text:

```
6>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Inno\MeetSchedAssist2019_v6.iss(1,1): warning : A message named "UninstallDisplayNameMarkCurrentUser" has not been defined for the "Romanian" language. Will use the English message from Default.isl.
6>D:\My Programs\2019\MeetSchedAssist\Inno\MeetSchedAssist2019_v6.iss(1,1): warning : such changes may not achieve what you are intending. See the "UsedUserAreasWarning" topic in help file for more information.
6>      Script compiled successfully in 25.402 seconds.
```

This one:

> such changes may not achieve what you are intending. See the "UsedUserAreasWarning" topic in help file for more information.

It seems incomplete. If I compile it with Inno Setup 6.0.5 I get the following build output:

```
Warning: A message named "UninstallDisplayNameMarkCurrentUser" has not been defined for the "Romanian" language. Will use the English message from Default.isl.
Warning: The [Setup] section directive "PrivilegesRequired" is set to "admin" but per-user areas (HKCU) are used by the script. Regardless of the version of Windows, if the installation is running in administrative install mode then you should be careful about making any per-user area changes: such changes may not achieve what you are intending. See the "UsedUserAreasWarning" topic in help file for more information.
```

As you can see, the sentence is more verbose in Inno Setup Compiler:

> *The [Setup] section directive "PrivilegesRequired" is set to "admin" but per-user areas (HKCU) are used by the script. Regardless of the version of Windows, if the installation is running in administrative install mode then you should be careful about making any per-user area changes:* such changes may not achieve what you are intending. See the "UsedUserAreasWarning" topic in help file for more information.

Everything up to and including the colon is missing from the warning.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, indeed the text was truncated (because of the additional colon). We will fix that in upcoming version, I will post full answer when we fix that issue.

Comment: @Slappy Any ETA on this?

Comment: We are waiting for final Inno 6.1.0 to be released - usually a week or two after Inno we release VI. See upcoming changes here: https://visual-installer.com/changelog.html#10410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

This issue was fixed in most recent version of Visual & Installer (November 2020).